# Поиск по ключевому слову в .value

Tags: javascript, поиск

Как осуществлять поиск по одну ключевому слову?

Приведу пример: есть value "Это **тестовое** сообщение 123", если в value курирует слово "**тестовое**", то происходит действие.

Мой код работает, только если value совпадает на 100%, а нужно чтобы он искал в этом value одно из ключевых слов. Надеюсь, объяснил доступно, спасибо.

```js
switch (opy.value) {
  case "Тестовый запрос.":
    alert('TEST')
    break
  case "RP":
    alert('RPO!')
    break
  case "WP":
    alert('WP')
    break
  default:
    //alert('Я таких значений не знаю')
}
```

Comment: А о каком языке программирования идет речь?

Comment: Добрый день. Речь идет о javascript.

Comment: Функция [indexOf()](https://learn.javascript.ru/string#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) есть.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам достаточен поиск по подстроке, то [String#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
if (opy.value.indexOf("тестовое") > -1) {
  // в opy.value есть подстрока "тестовое".
} else if (opy.value == "Тестовый запрос.") {
    alert('TEST')
} else if if (opy.value == "RP") {
    alert('RPO!')
// и т.д.
}
```

(Поскольку проверки более сложные, чем на точное равенство, `switch`-ем в таких случаях уже не пользуются)

Если вам нужен будет более сложный поиск, вроде "тестовое" или "тестовый" и не "протестовое", то уже тогда можно смотреть в сторону RegExp'ов.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужны регулярные выражения. Я покажу принцип, но регулярки нужно будет писать под конкретную задачу:

```js
var opy = {
  value: 'RP'
};

switch (true) {
  case opy.value.match(/RP/) !== null:
    alert('RPO!');
    break;
  default:
    alert('Я таких значений не знаю');
}
```

Comment: Нельзя, слышите, нельзя так использовать конструкцию `switch`. Пруф: http://jsfiddle.net/m01dkqyr/

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Точно, спасибо. Исправился.

Comment: То, что ваш код теперь работает, не делает его ни читаемым ни очевидным. На мой взгляд `switch(true)` вообще попахивает магией

Comment: Кстати вместо `String.prototype.match` эффективнее использовать `RegExp.prototype.test` ;)

Comment: мне кажется, конструкция `switch (true) {}` более наглядна, чем `if () {} elseif () {} elseif () {} else {}`